# Xamarin.Forms Carousel View

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using CarouselView to make a photo slider, sometimes the photos appear and other times they don't and appear a white background and it keep go and back like this

Xaml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test01"
   xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
   x:Class="Test01.MainPage">
    <StackLayout >
      <Label Text="Images " FontSize="30" Margin="20"/>
      <forms:CarouselView x:Name="MainCarouselView">
        <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding .}" x:Name="image" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      </forms:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test01
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

           var image = new List<ImageSource>
           {
           ImageSource.FromResource("Test01.Images.Photo01.jpeg"),
           ImageSource.FromResource("Test01.Images.Photo02.jpg"),
           ImageSource.FromResource("Test01.Images.Photo03.jpg"),
           ImageSource.FromResource("Test01.Images.Photo04.jpg"),
         };
         MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = image; 
       }
   }
```

}

problem is not with the photos because I switched them and kept trying with 1 photo and it works then add it the other photos and i get that issue

Comment: Could be image preloading issue especially if images are large and take long to download.. Consider lazy loading them..

Comment: @numbtongue i will try to resize all of them
Thanks

Comment: Its working .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be image preloading issue especially if images are large and take long to download.. Consider lazy loading them.. – boateng Sep 26 '18 at 17:30